# How to Share product2 records after migration?

Tags: sales-cloud, product2

I am working on data migration from one SF org to another SF.
After migration of product2 records, edit access to products  should be granted to few product manager users.
However, facing Salesforce limitations  where -

1. Product manager can not be set as owner as owner field is not
   available on Product
2. Can not set created by as product manager as
   setup audit fields permission is not supported on product object
3. Can not share product records with Product managers as sharing rule
   for internal users are not supported on product object.
4. Modify all permission not supported on product object

Product managers are getting access to edit new products which they are creating manually.
However, how to provide access to edit existing products which are migrated

Note: OWD is public read only which can not be opened up further as there are country wise product managers who should  not be able to update other countries products

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not possible.  See [this  Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgUVUAZ/allow-global-security-and-sharing-rules-settings-on-products).